# Set the minimum memory on my SQL Server with the service turned off

Tags: sql-server

I set the minimum memory to 100 MB on my SQL Server and did not start service.
Can I set the minimum memory back to 1024 MB? With the service turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:
[Start SQL Server with Minimal Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186400(v=sql.120).aspx)

> If you have configuration problems that prevent the server from
>   starting, you can start an instance of Microsoft SQL Server by using
>   the **minimal configuration startup option**. This is the startup option
>   `-f`. Starting an instance of SQL Server with minimal configuration automatically puts the server in single-user mode.

Comment: Thanks, adding that parameter I could enter to change the memory limits